# Storing Audit Storage

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, auditing

For storing audit entries for auditing purposes, I've been wrestling with how to record what data has changed.

I've done two different ways in the past, but I'm creating a new system now and am trying to figure out which to use:

1. Have an AuditEntry and AuditEntryChange table. Each changed field value goes in the AuditEntryChange table and has a FK to AuditEntry.
2. Have the changed fields and values stored in XML in the AuditEntry table in a single field.

Which of the above would be more performant for saving and querying? (including the impact of serialization/deserialization if using XML). And which would take up less space?

Also, is best practice to use GUID or int PKs for audit tables? I can think of reasons for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how you plan to query the audit table(s). Things to consider about audit tables are that in a typical scenario the records are read-only and are inserted far more often than queried.

I would lean towards option 2 for the following reasons:

- Inserting a single row is faster than inserting multiple rows with foreign key constraints.
- Having an XML field gives a great deal of flexibility in how the audit data is structured without having the worry about database schema.
- SQL Server can query XML columns using XPath syntax so you can still have some of the relational querying capabilities.
- Selecting many records, such as for display in a form, is also faster, since there are no joins.
- This model can be easily ported no NoSQL storage.
- XML serialization would only be involved when inserting from code or loading back into code. You can still query the XML column directly via SQL.
- I would assume that space requirements would increase, though this depends on the size of the indexes that may result from a relational model.

As for int vs Guid for audit tables I would go with a Guid because:

- If inserting using an ORM like NHibernate there is no select after insert to retrieve the generated ID. You can insert in batches efficiently.
- While a guid is 4 times larger, for a million records that results in a difference of about 10 MB. Is that really an issue? Especially since it is not likely to query by the PK of an audit log.
- Porting to other databases or storage mechanisms is easier.

Comment: Good comments about the Guid issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, for reporting it's a lot easier to have each field in a database.

GUID versus Integers depends on how many records you are going to have in the table. the integer takes 4 bytes versus 16 bytes for the GUID. If you are looking to have cross server deployment though GUIDs are a lot easier.

[Here is a good article on the pro's versus con's.](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-should-i-choose-for-my-primary-key.html)